# Image Processing algorithm code, interpreting pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm looking at The Pocket Handbook of Image Processing Algorithms (http://adaptiveart.eecs.umich.edu/2011/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/The-pocket-handbook-of-image-processing-algorithms-in-C.pdf), and I came across this code (below).

Can anyone help me understand the

```
*(Im->Data + (x)*Im->Cols + (y))
```

It's on pdf page 33.

```
#define pix(Im,x,y) \
        *(Im->Data + (x)*Im->Cols + (y))
/* Compute and return area for objects */

int area(struct Image *In, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, unsigned char ObjVal){
    long i, j, rows;
    int area_value = 0;

    for(i=x1; i<=x2; ++i)
        for(j=y1; j<=y2; ++j){
            if(pix(In,i,j)==ObjVal)++area_value;
        }
    return(area_value);
}
```

Comment: It's assuming a 2 dimensional array, stored in row-major order.  That's how you compute where datapoint(x,y) in a m by n 2D array.

Comment: The image is stored in an array, and what would be `p[x][y]` in a 2D array is `p[x * columns + y]` (or, equivalently, `*(p + x * columns + y)`).

Comment: use the modern c++ interface

Answer (score 1):

`Im` is a pointer to the Image struct

`Im->Data` is pointing to the buffer. Let's call it `buffer`

`Im->Cols` indicates the number of columns. `num_columns`

`buffer + x * num_columns + y` points to the pixel

By the way, this is a very inefficient way of traversing your image because you are calculating the position for every point.

You already have a 2 for loops there. There is no point on using this macro. You could easily use a single pointer and adjust it.

Something similar to this would be more efficient (I haven't tested it):

```
int area(struct Image *In, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, unsigned char ObjVal)
{
    int area_value = 0;

    unsigned char *p = Im->Data + x1 * Im->Cols + y1;  // Move to the first pixel

    int adj = In->Cols - (x2-x1)      // How much for the start of next row

    for(int i=x1; i<=x2; ++i, p += adj )
    {
        for(int j=y1; j<=y2; ++j, ++p)
        {
            if (*p == ObjVal) ++area_value;
        }
    }

    return area_value;
}
```